# Moving from Hidden to Collapse Bottom Sheets

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I am handling Bottom Sheets and I found that when Bottom Sheet is in hidden state and when I change the state of this Bottom Sheet it always move to Expanded state. If I give Collapse state then also it move to Expanded State.

So how can I stop that so that Collapse state is reached?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use [setSkipCollapsed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior#setskipcollapsed)

change the parameter to **false** like below:

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setSkipCollapsed(false);
```

Or you could use XML attribute

```
app:behavior_skipCollapsed="false"
```